# How to set input mask for a custom field

Tags: custom-fields

I want to record an identification number (only integer number) and it should only have 14 digits. I am thinking of something like this:
'--- --- --- -----'

Is it possible and how?
regards,
Guillaume

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in the UI afaik. I would use the validateForm hook in an extension to validate the number of digits? Documentation on the hook is here: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_validateForm/

Comment: ok thanks anyway Erik. I wanted it to be "simple" and wasn't willing to write some code.

Comment: Is there any update on this? I am looking for this feature too.